# How to add checkbox column with checkbox header in gridview dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having a `grid-view` on my `aspx page` without any template column and with `AutoGenerateColumns=false`.

I`m adding`BoundField`columns`dynamically`to`grid-view`.

And now I need to add a check box column with check box header into grid-view.
Can any one tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Now i find a solution on [how to add tempatefied(chekbox) to nestedgridview in code-behind](http://forums.asp.net/t/1365302.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i find a solution on [how to add tempatefied(chekbox) to nestedgridview in code-behind](http://forums.asp.net/t/1365302.aspx/1)